# How can I fix the "UIPopoverController is deprecated" warning?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller, deprecated

I am using this code:

```
mediaLibraryPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] 
                        initWithContentViewController:avc];
[self.mediaLibraryPopover presentPopoverFromRect:[theButton bounds] 
                          inView:theButton 
                          permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny 
                          animated:YES];
```

And I am getting this warning in Xcode 7:

> UIPopoverController is deprecated, first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - UIPopoverController is deprecated. Popovers are now implemented as UIViewController presentations. Use a modal presentation style of UIModalPresentationPopover and UIPopoverPresentationController.

Comment: The deprecation warning in UIStorybaordPopoverSegue.h has been improved, and now provides the direction: "Access destinationViewController.popoverPresentationController from your segue's performHandler..."

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You no longer need `UIPopoverController` for presenting a view controller.
Instead you can set the `modalPresentationStyle` of view controller to `UIModalPresentationPopover`.

You can use the following code for that:

```
avc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
avc.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = theButton;
[self presentViewController:avc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

> **UIModalPresentationPopover**
>
> In a horizontally regular environment, a
>   presentation style where the content is displayed in a popover view.
>   The background content is dimmed and taps outside the popover cause
>   the popover to be dismissed. If you do not want taps to dismiss the
>   popover, you can assign one or more views to the passthroughViews
>   property of the associated UIPopoverPresentationController object,
>   which you can get from the popoverPresentationController property.
>
> In a horizontally compact environment, this option behaves the same as
>   UIModalPresentationFullScreen.
>
> Available in iOS 8.0 and later.

Reference [UIModalPresentationStyle Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIModalPresentationStyle)

---

You need to set either `sourceView` or `barButtonItem` property, else it will crash with the following message:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'UIPopoverPresentationController (***) should have a non-nil
>   sourceView or barButtonItem set before the presentation occurs.'

For anchoring the popover arrow correctly, you need to specify the `sourceRect` property also.

```
avc.modalPresentationStyle                   = UIModalPresentationPopover;
avc.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
avc.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = theButton.frame;
[self presentViewController:avc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Refer [sourceView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverPresentationController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPopoverPresentationController/sourceView) and [sourceRect](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverPresentationController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPopoverPresentationController/sourceRect) for more details.

Comment: I found that I needed to change `avc.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;` and add `avc.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = theButton.frame;` for the popover to be positioned correctly.

Comment: @mark has a good point, but I don't think you need to change the sourceView.  When I did this I left `avc.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = theButton;` as-is and simply added `avc.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = theButton.bounds;`

Comment: How to dismiss a UIModalPresentationPopover in this way .? normal dismissviewcontroller .?

Comment: @mark If its presenting from presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem: what is the replacement .?

Comment: @Sat: Check the later half of the answer. You need to set `barButtonItem` property for showing the popover from a bar button item

Comment: @mark: Thanks . Got it :-) if there a way to check whether a popover is displaying already previously i done something like this if(popover.popoverVisible == YES) .

Comment: How to change the arrow direction ?

Comment: @Anz: You need to set the `permittedArrowDirections` property of popoverpresentationcontroller

Comment: @MidhunMP That doesn't helped me .I am running ipad pro ios 10,xcode 8.0 but the thing it shows the popover as in Iphone,rest ofthe ipads it works fine,can u pls help me out.

Comment: @Midhun MP answer is correct, but you don't even need to set the ModalPresentationStyle to popover as this is by default.

Comment: Setting sourceView + sourceRect produced the correct direction arrow for me.

Comment: yeap, basically this works for me. Thanks. I had to add this to main-thread though

Comment: How can I navigate to a partivulat view. I have used this for navigation

 [popover presentPopoverFromRect:self.titleView.frame inView:self.navigationController.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

Not sure how to navigate to the screen in UIPopoverPresentationController

Comment: AdditionallyMy popover shows the last item as its footer and not able to selet the item. Any updates on this is appreciated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76123444/unable-to-navigate-to-a-controller-using-the-uipopoverpresentationcontroller-pa

Answer (score 12):

Apple has the official way to present and configure popovers for iOS8 here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverPresentationController_class/index.html

While similar to @MidhunMP's answer, it's worth noting the paragraph:

> Configuring the popover presentation controller after calling
>   `presentViewController:animated:completion:` might seem
>   counter-intuitive but UIKit does not create a presentation controller
>   until after you initiate a presentation. In addition, UIKit must wait
>   until the next update cycle to display new content onscreen anyway.
>   That delay gives you time to configure the presentation controller for
>   your popover.

Configuration and responding to events can also be done via a delegate if you wanted (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate_protocol/index.html).

An example, setting aside the use of the delegate:

```
// Present the controller using the popover style.
controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];

// Popover presentation controller was created when presenting; now  configure it.
UIPopoverPresentationController *presentationController =
        [controller popoverPresentationController];
presentationController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft;
presentationController.sourceView = containerFrameOfReferenceView;
// arrow points out of the rect specified here
presentationController.sourceRect = childOfContainerView.frame;
```

But you'll also want to dismiss this. To do so without using a delegate, your presenting controller can just call:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

But what if I rotate my device, and the popover doesn't point to the right area? Your presenting controller can handle it:

```
// Respond to rotations or split screen changes
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size
       withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:nil 
                                 completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> _Nonnull context) {
        // Fix up popover placement if necessary, after the transition.
        if (self.presentedViewController) {
            UIPopoverPresentationController *presentationController =
                    [self.presentedViewController popoverPresentationController];
            presentationController.sourceView = containerFrameOfReferenceView;
            presentationController.sourceRect = childOfContainerView.frame;
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: How can I navigate to a particular view. I have used this for navigation using the UIPopoverController. In UIPopoverPresentationController how it can be done.[popover presentPopoverFromRect:self.titleView.frame inView:self.navigationController.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES]; Not sure how to navigate to the screen in UIPopoverPresentationController –

Answer (score 2):

If wanted directly from Button Action then this code can be used

```
SecondViewController *destinationViewController = (SecondViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"second"];
destinationViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
destinationViewController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.customButton;

// Set the correct sourceRect given the sender's bounds
destinationViewController.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = ((UIView *)sender).bounds;
[self presentViewController:destinationViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score -3):

EDIT: Regarding the down-votes. First a fun and relevant story:

http://www.folklore.org/StoryView.py?story=Negative_2000_Lines_Of_Code.txt

**I posted the answer below in order to help coders that might have been stuck in the mindset that iPad/iPhone still needed separate execution paths when presenting a media picker UI.** At the time of my original post this was not clear in the other answers. This solution path simplified my code and the future maintenance of my App. I think others might find this perspective useful because sometimes removing the right lines of code can be a good solution.

End of edit.

If you already have a working program and just want to get rid of the depreciation warning this could work for you.

In my code, and in my understanding, Popovers were introduced for the iPad and are iPad specific. Apple seems to have changed that. So, if you already have a working program that uses something like this:

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    // use popovers 
else
    //  don't use popovers
```

what you can do is just get rid of the iPad specific code (which is probably the code using Popovers) and have your program run the same instructions for both iPhone and iPad. This worked for me.

Comment: Answer is not useful: It is self-evident that removing code that causes a warning you don't want, will remove the warning.

Comment: However, it is not self-evident that you no longer need special code for dealing with the image picker on the iPad and that's the point I was trying to make.

Comment: Besides, your answer implies that removing the code still would provide popover functionality on iPads, which is not the case. It just completely drops popover support, which is an important iPad UI feature.

Comment: In my case this answer was helpful as: the PopoverController code was inserted by XCode from the template on creating the empty app. I never intended to directly support iPads - but I forgot to remove this unused code. Until now it throws a "deprecated" warning => Upvote +1