# Unable to navigate to a controller using the UIPopoverPresentationController _passthroughViews method in iOS using Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopoverpresentationcontroller

Unable to navigate to a controller using the UIPopoverPresentationController _passthroughViews method in iOS using Objective C.

I am trying to navigate to the controller view using the UIPopoverPresentationController's passthroughView. But I can't able to set this navigation and get an error and the app gets crashed. How can I resolve this?

Here I am additionally facing an error with the last item in the popover shows as a footer or not movable label and if I click this, there is no highlights,
Code:

```
SelectorViewController* sv = [[SelectorViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
sv.delegate = self;
sv.currentTopic = self.title;
NSLog(@" sv.currentTopic%@", sv.currentTopic);
sv.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 500);
sv.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
        
UIPopoverPresentationController *popoverpresentationController = sv.popoverPresentationController;
popoverpresentationController.delegate = self;
popoverpresentationController.sourceView = sender.view;
 [self present view controller:sv animated: YES completion: nil];  
   popover.delegate = self;
   if ([popover respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundColor:)])
         popover.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
         [sv release];
```

Comment: Can you add more details like what you are looking to achieve or a sample app which can reproduce the issue ? Didn't understand what is the value of _passthroughViews and why you are presenting twice in your code

Comment: "But I can't able to set this navigation and get an error and the app gets crashed" Could you share the full error message?

Comment: You should add error message what it say. Also i saw typo there: [[electorViewController alloc]. Missing an "s"?

Comment: UINavigationBar decoded as unlocked for UINavigationController, or navigationBar delegate set up incorrectly. Inconsistent configuration may cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to present a popover from a view controller and setting passthroughViews to the navigation controller's delegate. The `passthroughViews` property of `UIPopoverPresentationController` is an array of views.

The correct usage should be:

```
// Assuming `view1` and `view2` are views that you want the user to interact with while the popover is visible
popoverpresentationController.passthroughViews = @[view1, view2];
```

If you want to navigate to another controller when the popover is presented, you can do that in the popover's delegate method, `popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover`.

As for the issue where you're not able to interact with the content, make sure that the popover's `preferredContentSize` is big enough to display the tableview and its cells fully. Also, check the tableview's `contentSize`.

Comment: I have controller and one of the two values are differ I think. Because it opens in a popup window. So while click on the title it not navigating to the app